# Connecting randomly generated data to the source distribution they were sampled from

Tags: probability, distributions, simulation

The “simulation” approach to probabilities, where you have a model and you simply sample sufficiently many points from a distribution to (hopefully) estimate your probability well enough, is encountered everywhere in computer science.

The issue that I have with this approach is: Once you have the randomly sampled data points, there is no mathematical way of connecting them back to the distribution they came from. They are just a sequence of numbers (if you have many of them, you can test them for randomness, but that is really all you can do - and even that test will give you an answer that has a probability of it being true attached to it).

How do you go back from the list of numbers to the distribution that generated it?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean, but you might be interested in looking at things like the empirical process and the empirical cdf. Here you take random samples to make an empirical estimate of the distribution function and the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem tells us that if our samples are iid this empirical cdf convergences functionally to the underlying distribution F as the sample points goes to infinity non-parametrically. This kind of result is used often formally in machine learning and statistical learning theory, see chapter 3 http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/mlss_slt.pdf

Comment: what do you mean by mathematical way of connecting back? if you forgot what the source distribution was, but had some candidate distributions in mind, you could still identify which distribution the samples were drawn from by matching properties of the data, such as its higher order moments, with those same properties of one of the candidate distributions

Comment: @TyrelStokes Thanks, this was a really interesting pdf to read. I'm so unsure about the whole topic that it is even hard for me to precisely formulate what I am unsure about - but what you mentioned definitely points into the right direction.

Comment: @develarist Really, is that possible? Can you elaborate on that a bit, please? Or share some links?

Comment: Could you give example of what do you mean?

Comment: **probability integral transform** basically says that any random variable can be transformed into the uniform distribution, and back again, or to a different one. This is useful because if $X$ is your empirical data, and $Y$ is artificial data sampled from a candidate distribution that you think would fit, or was the source of, $X$, then you can transform both $X$ and $Y$ using **probability integral transform** to have a uniform distribution and compare their properties, or better yet transform the *transformed* (uniform) $X$ to the candidate distribution to see if they match up

Comment: @develarist If you take your two comments, and perhaps also illustrate them with a simple example, then that will an answer that works for me!